# Get year from boost date as string

Tags: c++, date, boost

I am using boost's date object
I want to get the year from this object as string or as int

I didn't find the simple way to do this
Thank you!
Ron

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>


std::string x = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>
                    (second_clock::local_time().date().year());
```

should do.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote these functions for a project of mine which you might find useful. I did it this way after I found the lexical_cast was causing a performance problem in my specific code. (No warranties, though it's run fine in our prod environment for a few years;)

```
using namespace boost;
    gregorian::date date_from_str(const char* dateStr,const char* format) {
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;
        sscanf_s(dateStr,format,&year,&month,&day);
        return gregorian::date(year,month,day);
    }
    std::string date_to_str(const gregorian::date& date,const char* format) {
        char buf[10];
        gregorian::date::ymd_type ymd = date.year_month_day();
        sprintf_s(buf,sizeof(buf),format,ymd.year,ymd.month,ymd.day);
        return std::string(buf);
    }

    gregorian::date dateInt_to_date(int dateInt) {
        const int day = dateInt % 100;
        const int month = (dateInt / 100) % 100;
        const int year = dateInt / 10000;
        return gregorian::date(year,month,day);
    }
```

You can edit this to just return the year part

Comment: `sprintf_s` isn't very C++ way, it even compiles only on MSVC :)

Comment: Yep! But the transform to regular c++ is easy :) And I figured, this might be useful nonetheless to others as well as @Ron Gross.

Comment: Why the downvote? It date_to_str achieves what you want in an efficient manner and the others are helpful.

Comment: Let me suppose...because there are other methods (without lexical_cast) to convert to string (in case performance are an issue). strstream or boost's formatters (just to mention) without a fixed size **C** buffer (date length may vary **a lot** according to locale). That said code is pretty weak (unsafe) and does not take into account differences between dates in other countries. Enough?

Comment: I thought about this a bit. Given a gregorian date, all known locales use a 2 or 4 digit representation for the year. There's not the variation with dd/mm or mm/dd etc formats. So I stand by my answer for the date_to_str() conversion. For a full date, absolutely there is more that could be done to make it safe.

Answer (score 0):

A good option is to use the inbuilt function in the boost library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp" //include all types plus i/o

using namespace boost::gregorian;
using namespace std;

date d(2000, Jan, 1);
string a = to_simple_string(d);
```